# JMPing to 0x7C00 in bootloader does not cause infinite loop

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, x86-16

I am creating a bootloader and wanted to create an infinite loop out of interest by jumping to the address 0x7C00.

As bootloaders are loaded to 0000:7C00, I expect when I call `JMP 0x7C00`, the code would go to the beginning of the program. Except it calls the code once and that's it.

Here is my code:

```
  1 BITS 16
  2 ORG 0x7C00
  3 
  4 MOV AX, 0
  5 MOV DS, AX
  6 MOV SI, 0x7C00
  7 
  8 LEA BX, [msg]
  9 
 10 printMsg:
 11   MOV AL, [BX]
 12   INC BX
 13   CMP AL, 0
 14   JZ return
 15   CALL printc
 16   JMP printMsg
 17 JMP 0x7C00
 18   
 19 printc:
 20   MOV AH, 0Eh
 21   int 10h
 22   RET
 23 
 24 return:
 25   RET
 26 
 27 
 28 msg: db "Hello",0
 29 
 30 times 510-($-$$) db 0x90
 31 dw 0xAA55
```

I have also tried to create a `start` label on line 3 and either `CALL start` or `JMP start` on line 17. None of this seems to work though.

Comment: Where is your `jmp`? The only one I see is the `JMP printMsg`.  Also you don't `call printMsg` so the `RET` at `return:` will have nowhere to go.

Comment: *As bootloaders are loaded to 0000:7C00* you unfortunately can't depend on that.  Some "broken" BIOSes apparently jump into the MBR with CS:IP= `07C0:0000`.  But yes, with that ORG directive, NASM will assemble `jmp 0x7c00` into a relative jump as if you'd put a label at the top of your file.  But really you should just do that in the first place; x86 doesn't have absolute direct near jumps, only relative, absolute indirect, and far jumps (that set a new CS as well as IP).  Anyway, use the BOCHS debugger to single-step your code, and if that doesn't work post a [mcve] of what happens.

Comment: Sorry @Jester I posted the wrong code. I've updated it.

Comment: Your `JMP 0x7C00` is immediately after another `jmp` so it will never be reached.

Comment: Thanks @Jester If you create that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Use a debugger to single-step your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't `call printMsg` so the `RET` at `return:` will have nowhere to go. Also your `jmp 0x7c00` is in the wrong place, it's unreachable.

Furthermore, as [Peter said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58710468/jmping-to-0x7c00-in-bootloader-does-not-cause-infinite-loop#comment103715140_58710468) you are not guaranteed to have `CS:IP = 0000:7C00` it could be `07C0:0000` depending on BIOS implementation. Still, with that `ORG 0x7C00` directive, NASM will assemble `jmp 0x7c00` into a relative jump as if you'd put a label at the top of your file. But really you should just do that in the first place.

A fixed version could thus look like:

```
BITS 16
ORG 0x7C00

start:

XOR AX, AX
MOV DS, AX

; you could also put the start label here
; no need to reload DS
LEA BX, [msg]
CALL printMsg
JMP start

printMsg:
  MOV AL, [BX]
  INC BX
  TEST AL, AL
  JZ return
  CALL printc
  JMP printMsg
return:
  RET

printc:
  MOV AH, 0Eh
  int 10h
  RET

msg: db "Hello",0

times 510-($-$$) db 0x90
dw 0xAA55
```